# findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition recycler view always returning -1

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I tried all possible solutions for this issue, but it didn't work.

Here is my xml:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:background="#F5F5F5"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="#F5F5F5"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

     <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp">
    </LinearLayout

     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/photographer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white_color"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/feed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="No Records"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout>
```

Here is my code,

```
    adapter = new Adapter(getActivity(), lists, this, modelarray);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    rvFeedList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    rvFeedList.setAdapter(getFeedDataListAdapter);
    rvFeedList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    rvFeedList.setItemAnimator(null);

    rvFeedList.addOnScrollListener(new PaginationScrollListener(mLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        protected void loadMoreItems() {
            if (IS_MORE) {
                isLoading = true;
                currentPage++;
                getFeedData();
            } else {
            }
        }


        @Override
        public boolean isLastPage() {

            return isLastPage;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLoading() {
            isLastItemDisplaying(rvFeedList);
            return isLoading;
        }

        @Override
        public int getTotalPageCount() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                         int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);


                 Log.e("Test","Log::"+"onScrollStateChanged:Complete"+mLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition());

            if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                //get the recyclerview position which is completely visible and first
                int positionView = ((LinearLayoutManager)
                        rvFeedList.getLayoutManager()). mLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                Log.e("Log::VISISBLE", positionView + "");
                if (positionView >= 0) {
                    if (oldFocusedLayout != null) {
                        //Stop the previous video playback after new scroll
                        MyPlayer myPlayer = (MyPlayer) oldFocusedLayout.findViewById(R.id.my_player);
                        if(myPlayer!=null)
                            myPlayer.pause();
                    }


                    currentFocusedLayout = ((LinearLayoutManager) rvFeedList.getLayoutManager()).findViewByPosition(positionView);
                    MyPlayer myPlayer = (MyPlayer) currentFocusedLayout.findViewById(R.id.my_player);
                    //to play video of selected recylerview, videosData is an array-list which is send to recyclerview adapter to fill the view. Here we getting that specific video which is displayed through recyclerview.
                    if(myPlayer!=null)
                        myPlayer.start();
                    oldFocusedLayout = currentFocusedLayout;
                }
            }

        }

    });
```

My requirement is , my recycler view contains videos , so I tried to get the completely view position and using that tried to play video if it old position I want to pause that video.

Comment: you can get current visible position from layout manager. `layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();`

Comment: I need to find  findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition then only I can play video smoothly @kartikmalik

Comment: facing issue when first item visible half and second item visible half

Comment: Can you please share screenshot of your recyclerview items from device?

Comment: a similar video playing with exoplayer with recyclerview https://codingwithmitch.com/blog/playing-video-recyclerview-exoplayer-android/

Comment: @Raghunandan Surely I ll try and let you know